# Creating a simple factory class in C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a factory class to simplify creating objects of another class without polluting the constructors of the target class (I think that's what factories are for)

This is what I have at the moment.

```
public class QFactory
{
    public Quiz.Question q(string text, string buttonname)
    {
        Quiz.Question question = new Quiz.Question();
        question.QuestionText = text;
        question.QuestionImage = buttonname;

        return question;
    }

    public Quiz.Answer a(string answerText, bool answerRight = false)
    {
        Quiz.Answer answer = new Quiz.Answer();
        answer.text = answerText;
        answer.correct = answerRight;
        return answer;
    }
}
```

In order to use it to create Quiz.Question and Quiz.Answer objects, I have to use it in the following way.

```
Quiz.Question q = (new QFactory()).q("What is a tomato?","But_01_Idle");

Quiz.Answer a = (new QFactory()).a("fruit",true);
Quiz.Answer b = (new QFactory()).a("vegetable");
Quiz.Answer c = (new QFactory()).a("animal");

q.Answers = new List<Quiz.Answer>{a,b,c}; // add a,b,c answer to the question
```

How would I change the QFactory class so that its usage is like this instead (singletons?)?

```
Quiz.Question q = QFactory.q("what is a Tomato?","But_01_Idle");
...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make the method static in the factory

Comment: A static class is a class with only static methods and fields, so you can (and should) mark the class static once all methods in it are static.

Comment: The normal use of a factory is to create an object of a type that is unknown to the caller. I.e., the declared return type is an interface (IQuestion) and the factory can create instances of some concrete type of question. The idea is that the type of question produced by the factory can be changed in the future without the rest of the code noticing. So the factory works as a decoupling.

Comment: In this case it seems ok but I wouldn't rush with making everything static. If another family of question/answer objects ever need to be constructed by a different concrete factory going the non-static Abstract Factory pattern way would be better.

Comment: This should be comment

Answer (score 4):

here is simple example of factory design pattern implementation in C#. this may be help full to you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Factory
{
    public abstract class DbServer
    {
        //method need to be implemented by inherited classes
        public abstract string GetDbServerName();
    }
    public class MsSqlServerDb : DbServer
    {
        //overridden method
        public override string GetDbServerName()
        {
            return "MS Sql Server";
        }
    }
    public class OracleDb : DbServer
    {
        //overridden method
        public override string GetDbServerName()
        {
            return "Oracle Database Server";
        }
    }
    //factory class that will be used to create objects
    public static class DatabaseFactory
    {
        //return the required object
        public static DbServer GetDb(string DbName)
        {
            if (DbName == "Ms Sql Server")
            {
                return new MsSqlServerDb();
            }
            if (DbName == "Oracle Database Server")
            {
                return new OracleDb();
            }
            return new MsSqlServerDb();

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //get the ms sql server object
            DbServer dbServer = DatabaseFactory.GetDb("Ms Sql Server");
            //return ms sql server
            string dbName = dbServer.GetDbServerName();
            //print the name on output window
            Console.WriteLine("Server Name : " + dbName);
            //get the oracle database server object
            dbServer = DatabaseFactory.GetDb("Oracle Database Server");
            //return oracle server name
            dbName = dbServer.GetDbServerName();
            //print the name to output window
            Console.WriteLine("Server Name : " + dbName);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the `a` and `q` methods `static`. They are not referencing any instance variables in the `QFactory` class so they can be `static`.

Since the whole `QFactory` class lacks members you can make the entire class `static`, preventing any instantiation of it. A static class more becomes a grouping of methods than a class in the usual meaning, which is exactly the case here. Marking the class as static makes it clearer that this is not an object which can carry state.

Answer (score 0):

Mark methods q() and a() as `static`, class `QFactory` should be static as well because all methods are `static`